# Broken Images in New React-Router-Dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use one component as the navbar throughout my react app. The navbar has an image on it as a logo. Outside of the nested routes the logo in the navbar displays just fine. However, when I try to use the navbar inside of the nested routes, the logo image link appears as broken. Below is how I have imported my logo image and after that is how I have nested the routes:

```
    <Link to="/" className="links">
      <span className="logo">
        <img src="./assets/logo.jpg" alt="" />
      </span>
    </Link>
```

---

```
function App() { return (
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" alement={<About />} />
        <Route path="services">
          <Route index element={<Services />} />
          <Route path=":serviceId" element={<Service />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Instead of writing the image path as

```
<img src="./assets/logo.jpg" alt="" />
```

Remove the dot before assets and just leave it as:

```
<img src="/assets/logo.jpg" alt="" />
```

This will ensure that the assets folder loads from the root and is accessible from anywhere throughout the app